# I have a Meteor app and needs to read data, from the /public/_assets/results/mmresults.json file, within the /client/controllers.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, json

I have a Meteor app and needs to read data, from a file "/public/_assets/results/mmresults.json", within the file "/client/controllers.js".

I do not want to read from the file "/server/app.js"

The following is my file "/public/_assets/results/mmresults.json":

```
{items:[{"Draw_Date":'2016-01-01',"Number_0":"1","Number_1":"1","Number_2":"2","Nmber_3":"3","Number_4":"4","Number_5":"5"},{"Draw_Date":'2016-01-03',"Number_0":"2", "Number_1":"2","Number_2":"3","Nmber_3":"4","Number_4":"5","Number_5":"6"}]}
```

The following is my codes in my "/client/controllers.js" file:

```
$.getJSON("_assets/results/mmresults.json", function(data, status) {
   alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

The codes in my controllers.js file doesn't work. Does $.getJSON work on client side or only works on server side?

Also, my app will be running on iOS 10 iPhone and the mmresults.json file needs to be resided on the iPhone and not on the Meteor server.

Please advice.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues trying to access files on mobile devices because of security and CORS. Try to do this as a simple import of the data as an object.

Create a directory at the same level as the client folder called "imports" (assuming you don't have this folder already). In that directory, create a file called itemsPublic.js with this content:

```
'use strict';

var itemsPublic;

itemsPublic = 
                {
                   "items":[
                      {
                         "Draw_Date":"2016-01-01",
                         "Number_0":"1",
                         "Number_1":"1",
                         "Number_2":"2",
                         "Nmber_3":"3",
                         "Number_4":"4",
                         "Number_5":"5"
                      },
                      {
                         "Draw_Date":"2016-01-03",
                         "Number_0":"2",
                         "Number_1":"2",
                         "Number_2":"3",
                         "Nmber_3":"4",
                         "Number_4":"5",
                         "Number_5":"6"
                      }
                   ]
                };


var exports = module.exports = itemsPublic;
```

Now, in your client code, you can import this object by adding this code at the top of your file:

```
var items = require('/imports/publicJson.js');
```

To access the data, simply interact with it as a normal object:

```
console.log(items);
```